# PHP Regex matches beween Slash and Subtract

Tags: php, regex

Hello I need a regex to get a string "trkfixo" from

```
SIP/trkfixo-000072b6
```

I was trying to use `explode` but I prefer a regex solution.

```
$ex = explode("/",$sip);
$ex2 = explode("-",$ex[1]);
echo $ex2[0];
```

Comment: What regexes have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `'~/([^-]+)~'`:

```
$re = '~/([^-]+)~'; 
$str = "SIP/trkfixo-000072b6"; 
preg_match($re, $str, $match);
echo $match[1]; // => trkfixo
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ6sZ9/1) and a [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/bR4ooJ)

**Pattern details**:

- `/` - matches a `/`
- `([^-]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more (`+`) symbols other than `-` (due to the fact that `[^-]` is a *negated character class* that matches any symbols other than all symbols and ranges inside this class).

Comment: sealabr: Have you tried out this approach? Please let know if anything is still unclear or you need more help with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$match = preg_match('/\/[a-zA-Z]-/', "SIP/trkfixo-000072b6");
```

Comment: You should swap the two variables. Also, are you sure this is written in PHP?

Comment: OP needs to get `trkfixo`. This code line - `$match = preg_match('/\/[a-zA-Z]-/', "SIP/trkfixo-000072b6");` - only fetches the number of occurrences of `/`+ASCII letter+`-` in the input string. The regex and the code do not do what is required, see http://ideone.com/NpzmYx. This answer is rather unhelpful.

Comment: Ahh Wiktor, I've had a couple poorer quality answers today. I'll correct it as soon as I'm home